# Access glassfish remotely

Tags: linux, glassfish

I’ve installed glassfish application server on linux. So, I deployed an application, and all works fine. But I can Access this server only from local network. I can’t access glassfish remotely (can't access application or glassfish administration panel). Where can be a problem? Thanks!

Comment: do you get `Secure Admin must be enabled to access the DAS remotely` error when you try to access server control panel?

Comment: No I get "page not found error" :)

Comment: Have you checked firewalls etc.? Can you definitely reach the remote server from the local one on other ports, e.g. SSH? A little more information in the question would be helpful, are these both on the same network? Over the Internet? Are they in the cloud (AWS/Azure etc)?

Comment: could you elaborate a little more about your network topology ?

Answer (score 2):

> asadmin --host yourdomain --port 4848 enable-secure-admin

You can read here : [Glassfish Secure Admin Must Be Enabled To Access The DAS Remotely](http://ubuntuwizard.wordpress.com/2014/10/08/glassfish-secure-admin-must-be-enabled-to-access-the-das-remotely/)